# How did Jeffrey Sinclair become a Minbari?

Tags: babylon-5

I never really understood this.

[Jeffrey Sinclair](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/chars/sinclair.html) disappeared after Season 1 due to the actor departing the show. When he returned it was as a Minbari.

The predestination time travel paradox and him becoming a different species never made sense to me.

Can anyone give an explanation?

Comment: Actually, it wasn't due to the actor leaving the show.  This was pre-planned from the start by the showrunner, J. Michael Straczynski.  He wasn't sure just when Sinclair would leave B5 at first, but then decided to do it at the end of season 1.  So Sinclair's disappearance was fully intentional.

Comment: In this case, there's no paradox - it's the best example of a [Stable Time Loop](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StableTimeLoop) I've ever seen.

Comment: @TangoOversway Ahh OK. I just knew that the actor had wanted to leave the show and Straczynski was OK with that, so thought it was a nice way to write him out.

Comment: @Izkata How so? It seems to be a predestination paradox. Sinclair is only be able to become Valen because he was recognized as Valen, and thus spared. There is no clear beginning.

Comment: @RCToaster Sorry, I misunderstood the exact paradox you mentioned.  More specifically, the timeline never changed, and objects that went back in time weren't the same objects from the first time (the Triluminaries came from the planet, for example, not the Minbari homeworld).  See the references to Stable Time Loop on the [TemporalParadox](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TemporalParadox) TVTropes page, for more examples.

Comment: @RCToaster: I remember Joe Straczynski discussing this on GEnie when it was happening - as he did a lot of what was going on while he was producing B5.  He talked about how he realized it was time to make the change and notified Michael O'Hare and how they were thrilled with getting Bruce Boxleitner as the new commander and that Michael O'Hare would even be back for a few appearances during the next season.  So it wasn't that the actor wanted to leave, it was always part of Joe's plan (the entire series was planned out before the first scene was ever shot) that Sinclair would leave B5.

Comment: @Izkata it is still a [predestination paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_paradox) as I understand it. To quote from the wiki "*It exists when a time traveller is caught in a loop of events that "predestines" or "predates" them to travel back in time*". It has always seemed like lazy writing to me.

Comment: @TangoOversway I was getting my info from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Sinclair#O.27Hare.27s_departure), which states: "*After one full season, both O'Hare and series executive producer/creator J. Michael Straczynski made the mutual and amicable decision for the character and actor to depart as a regular.*" Which made it seem like the actor wanted to leave, at least in part. The references seem reliable. I thought I recalled something about the switch coming sooner than had been anticipated as well, but can't find anything on that.

Comment: If someone hasn't mentioned this already, I highly suggest you add some spoiler tags of some sort here. That's a fairly big plot point in the show.

Comment: @RCToaster: You probably already know this, but a couple of years ago, after O'Hare's death, JMS revealed O'Hare's long battle with mental illness: *"...during the filming of the first season of Babylon 5, O'Hare began having paranoid delusions. Halfway through filming, his hallucinations worsened. It became increasingly difficult for O'Hare to continue work...Straczynski agreed to keep his condition secret to protect O'Hare's career. O'Hare agreed to complete the first season but would be written out of the second season so that he could seek treatment."* (Source: Wikipedia article on O'Hare)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

He did not reappear as a Minbari.  He came back as his original human self.  He did not change into a Minbari until 3x16 - 3x17, the "War Without End" two-parter.

> They were the ones that caused the disappearance of Babylon 4, and took it back 1000 years into the past to use as a base in the last Shadow war.  During the journey back in time, he used a Triluminary from the Great Machine to become Minbari, which would later become the same one Delenn had used to become human.  He became Valen, a Minbari not born of Minbar.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I tend not to think about spoilers when I post.

Answer (score 4):

He was human with a Minbari soul.   It's a bit of a paradox but stable, it requires a closed time loop that can't change and has no initial beginning.  He went back in time and merged human and minbari, causing minbari souls to be born to humans, which caused him to exist, which caused him to be able to go back and become Valen, closing the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ohare left the show on an ending the season agreement due to increasing effects of mental illness that eventually claimed him in 2010 or 2011. It is said to have not been preplanned.

There's some more information [here](http://www.blastr.com/2013-5-28/straczynski-reveals-moving-story-why-michael-ohare-left-babylon-5).

And a quote from the same article;

> In 2012, Michael O'Hare, who played the original Commander of Babylon
>   5, Jeffrey Sinclair, passed away. During his life, however, fans were
>   unaware of the fact that he suffered from delusions and paranoia due
>   to mental illness.
>
> That was the real reason he left the show after
>   only one season. Straczynski explained how O'Hare struggled, how he
>   was barely able to come back for a two-parter to close his character's
>   story, but above all, that O'Hare wanted people to know the truth
>   after his death.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your answer. Can you bring any sources or citations to back up your claim?

Comment: Joe revealed the Michal O'Hare had had a mental illness at the Phoenix Comiccon last year, and that this was the reason why he left when he did.  However there is no indication that this lead to his death. (I've tried to find a transcript of the announcement, which I'm sure I've read, but come up blank - plenty of Youtube)

Comment: I've edited to include a link to an article which also has a link to the YT video you mentioned. RIP Commander Sinclair.

Comment: This is quite correct, but it doesn't answer the question asked, which is: What was the mechanism behind the character returning and changing into a Minbari?

Answer (score 0):

There was a device found on the planet that B5 orbeted. He used this device to change himself into a Minbari. Delenn also used a similar device to change herself into a half Human half Minbari hybrid. Also found on this planet were the time warp devices Sinclair and the other B5 crew used to travel though time.

Comment: Although this isn't wrong, it does largely replicate the info in an earlier (and high voted) answer.